# ElvUI. How to show itemlevel in unit frame?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

It is nice to see levels of your group members immediately in the unitframes. With ElvUI you can do it using [level] variable in unitframe options for your aim or group.
But often item level is much more important.

Is it possible to show average item level of a player in the ElvUI unit frame (preferable group unitframe, but aim unitframe is also ok)? Some text-variable like [level] may be, or an addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you make an addon for it, ElvUI at its core will not do this.
Since the UI does make a note of easy to read ilvls on gear pieces for all toons you use the UI for, the same cannot be done unless your inspecting the other player.  Since this is not always possible.  Having an addon to data fetch the info would be better, however it would have a slight margin of error since the data does not sync until log out and back in.
The PUG tool for Raiding actually helps with this since it sends the data in real time.  But the problem would stil lie within ElvUI Core programming since it was never intended to keep track of ilvls of anyone your in a party with nor does it have the capacity to do such a thing.

Your better off finding an addon that does this or making one yourself.